# Add-in for desktop and web Outlook

Tags: outlook, office365, yeoman, outlook-addin, office-js

I am new in Office add-in development and little bit confused about creation JS plug-ins for Outlook. Actually we can create one add-in which will be available on all platforms: Outlook on Mac/PC, Outlook.com and Outlook 365.
But what about tools for it? According Outlook development [documentation](https://dev.outlook.com/MailAppsGettingStarted/GetStarted/outlook-dot-com), we can use *Yeoman* generator for creating Office add-ins. However in my VisualStudio Community 2015 is type of project like "Web add-in", where I can chose Outlook add-in. So is there some difference between *Yeoman* generator and VisualStudio Web add-in projects?

Comment: You can get basic understand how to starts developing on Add-in with VS in this [link](http://simonjaeger.com/create-a-compose-mode-mail-add-in-for-outlook/#exercise-12-edit-the-manifest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Visual Studio` is the main tool for creating Outlook plugins. You can also use `Visual Studio Code` for developing web-based solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Office add-in is nothing else as "manifest.xml" file + your web application (HTML + JS). Web application is what your VS Code is help you to create. The manifest part is something which you able to write yourself, coy it from an example or use YO Generator to produce it for you. More on how to build office add-ins: [Office Add-ins with VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/office) and how to use generator: [Yo Code - Extension Generator](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/tools/yocode)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question "is there some difference between Yeoman generator and VisualStudio Web add-in projects?": There is no *fundamental* difference. First choose whether to develop your Outlook Web Add-in with VS or with some non-VS tool. If you use VS, then use the project templates in VS. If you use any other development tool, use the yeoman-generated templates.

Occasionally, templates can get out-of-date. For example, recommended practices may change, or the manifest XML schema may be expanded. As a general rule, the yeoman-generated templates are updated more frequently than the ones generated in VS. For this reason, there may be small differences in the templates (besides the differences that are inherent to the differences in the tools).